# when I used gulp and browser-sync, It made a mistake

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

When I change the code in `HTML` and `CSS`, it responds:

> [BS] Reloading Browsers...
>   [15:34:19] Finished 'browserSync' after 1.46 ms
>   /c/Users/weiyinpeng/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 14:  8084 Segmentation fault      node "$basedir/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js" "$@"

Here is my `gulpfile.js` code.

```
        let gulp = require("gulp");
    let browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
    let postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
    let autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer-core");
    let postcssSimpleVars = require("postcss-simple-vars");
    let postcssMixins = require("postcss-mixins");
    let postcssNested = require("postcss-nested");
    let sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
    let babel = require("gulp-babel")
    let concat = require("gulp-concat")
    let rename = require("gulp-rename")
    let md5 = require("gulp-md5")
    let uglify = require("gulp-uglify")
    let pump = require("pump")
    let del = require("del")
    // Css process.
    gulp.task("PC-postcss", ()=>{
        var processors = [
            postcssMixins,
            postcssSimpleVars,
            postcssNested,
            autoprefixer({
                // browsers: ['last 20 version', 'safari > 5', 'ff > 31', 'opera 12.1', 'IOS 6', 'IE > 7', 'Android 4','> 10%']
                browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari > 5', 'ff > 31', 'opera 12.1', 'IOS 6', 'IE 8', 'Android 4','> 1%']


            })];

        return gulp.src(["./today-pc/**/*.scss"])
            .pipe(postcss(processors))
            .pipe(rename({
                extname:".css"
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./today-pc/"));

    });
    // Css process.
    gulp.task("M-postcss", ()=>{
        var processors = [
            postcssMixins,
            postcssSimpleVars,
            postcssNested,
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 version']
            })];

        return gulp.src(["./today-m/**/*.scss"])
            .pipe(postcss(processors))
            .pipe(rename({
                extname:".css"
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./today-m/"));

    });
    gulp.task("textConcat", ()=>{
        gulp.src("fuck/*.js")
            .pipe(babel({
                presets:["es2015"]
            }))
            .pipe(concat("all.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dest"))
    })
    // 名字不能用index.js，today.js 编译后称today-concat.js
    gulp.task("es2015", function (){
        gulp.src("./**/today.js")
        .pipe(babel({
            presets :["es2015"]
        }))
        .pipe( rename(function(path) {
            path.basename += "-concat";
        }) )
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"))
    })
    // 改名
    gulp.task("testRename",()=>{
        gulp.src("fuck/demo.js",{base:process.cwd()})
            .pipe(rename({
                dirname:"main/text/ciao",
                basename:"aa",
                prefix:"bonjour-",
                suffix:"-hold",
                extname:".jsd"
            }
                ))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dest"))
    })
    // md5的文件名字编译
    gulp.task("md5",()=>{
        gulp.src("fuck/demo3.js")
            .pipe(md5({
                cwd:"dest/"
            }))
            .pipe(md5())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dest/"))
    })
    // js压缩
    gulp.task("uglify1",()=>{
            gulp.src("fuck/demo4.js")
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dest"))
    })
    gulp.task("jsmin",  ()=> {
        gulp.src("src/js/index.js")
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
    });
    // 保存同步浏览器
    gulp.task("browserSync", ()=>{
        browserSync.reload();
    })
    gulp.task("pc-server",["PC-postcss","es2015"], ()=>{
        browserSync.init({
            server: "today-pc/"
        });
        gulp.watch("./today-pc/**/*.scss", ["PC-postcss"]);
        gulp.watch("./today-pc/**/today.js", ["es2015"]);
        gulp.watch(["./today-pc/**/today-concat.js","./today-pc/**/index.css","./today-pc/**/*.html"], ["browserSync"]);
    })
    gulp.task("m-server",["M-postcss","es2015"], ()=>{
        browserSync.init({
            server: "today-m/"
        });
        gulp.watch("./today-m/**/*.scss", ["M-postcss"]);
        gulp.watch("./today-m/**/today.js", ["es2015"]);
        gulp.watch(["./today-m/**/today-concat.js","./today-m/**/index.css","./today-m/**/*.html"], ["browserSync"]);
    })
    gulp.task("default",["pc-server"])
```

Comment: so basically it is going in infinite loop somewhere... mostly in your watch task

Answer (score 0):

I had checked my code for a few days,and found out which is wrong with it . The task in PC-postcss should change to :

```
gulp.task("PC-postcss", ()=>{
    var processors = [
        postcssMixins,
        postcssSimpleVars,
        postcssNested,
        autoprefixer({ 
            browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari > 5', 'ff > 31', 'opera 12.1', 'IOS 6', 'IE 8', 'Android 4','> 1%'] 
        })];

    return gulp.src(["./today-pc/static/css/*.scss"])
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname:".css"
        })) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./today-pc/static/css/"))
         // .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});
```

The path in the gulp.src is wrong.It must get something wrong in the path in the gulp's Path analysis. Thank you all. I use stackoverflow for the first time ,and I am sorry for those I had did.